# Snowflake Inner join with same table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to bring this query in Snowflake. But, getting huge numbers with the last 3 inner joins which has same tables with different conditions.

```
select count(*) from table2; --5
select count(*) from table_3;--2824134
select count(*) from table1;--478015
```

Original Query:

```
select * from
from table1 d_tbl  
inner join table2 r on r.number = d_tbl.number  
inner join table_3 Zero on Zero.ID_I = r.id and Zero.time <= d_tbl.starttime and Zero.typeid in (7,19)
inner join table_3 first on first.ID_I = r.id and first.time <= Zero.time and first.typeid in (8,9)
inner join table_3 second on second.ID_I = r.id and second.time >= d_tbl.endtime and second.typeid in (8,9)
where d_tbl.mode = 0;
```

I tried breaking the queries into 3 parts.

```
create temp table tb1 as
select *  
from table1 d_tbl
inner join table2 r on r.number = d_tbl.number ;

create temp table tb2 as
select ID_I , time as time as Zero_time,time as first_time,time as second_time 
from table_3  
where  typeid in (8,9,7,19)
Note: saving the time column with different names for reference.


create temp table final_table as
select * from tb1 r
inner join tb2  
on tb2.ID_I = r.id
where tb2.Zero_time <= r.starttime
and tb2.first_time <= Zero.time
and tb2.second_time >= r.endtime
```

Basically, I am trying to break the conditions in the joins to different parts.
This same logic has to be applied for different tables and do a union all for final table values.

Please help if this would work or let me know if this shall be handled with a better approach that executes faster.

TIA.

Comment: _getting huge numbers_ means your join conditions are incorrect and you are "double counting"

Comment: For example is `number` unique in either `table1` or `table2`? if no you'll just double count. When you broke it into parts were you able to isolate where the double counting started?

Comment: From your query it appears you want to select a column value multipls times based on different conditions. Rather then using multiple inner joins you can use CASE statement and just join table3 one time.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid. Yes.  The double counting happens during the time comparison in those last 3 joins. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj you mean to add a case statement with conditions ? Sorry  I didn’t get that.

Comment: @Anand yes that is correct, please refer the sample code I have shared. Also, it helps to get more precise response If you can share some sample data and expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try and convert following -

```
select * from
from table1 d_tbl  
inner join table2 r on r.number = d_tbl.number  
inner join table_3 Zero on Zero.ID_I = r.id 
AND Zero.time <= d_tbl.starttime and Zero.typeid in (7,19)
inner join table_3 first on first.ID_I = r.id 
AND first.time <= Zero.time and first.typeid in (8,9)
inner join table_3 second on second.ID_I = r.id 
AND second.time >= d_tbl.endtime and second.typeid in (8,9)
where d_tbl.mode = 0;
```

To something like below -

```
select whatever-columns,
case when t3.time <= d_tbl.starttime 
AND Zero.typeid in (7,19) then t3.time_1 end as zero_time,
case when t3.time <= zero_time 
AND Zero.typeid in (8,9) then t3.time_1 end as first_time, --- snowflake allows to select/reference previous column 
case when t3.time >= d_tbl.endtime 
AND second.typeid in (8,9)then t3.time_1 end as second_time
from 
table1 d_tbl  
inner join table2 r on r.number = d_tbl.number  
inner join table_3 t3 on t3.ID_I = r.id 
where d_tbl.mode = 0;
```

This will help to reduce data-set being searched by avoiding multiple inner join on same table that has most records.